# iFrame in my application is called using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application there is a main page which has lots of links. There is a space on the right hand side of the page which is a frame. Now, depending on link which user clicks the right hand side frame gets populated.

Now the question is, when I see the page source I get something like this(pasted at the bottom of the page).

However, when I see in firebug(mozilla extension) I get proper html code with all the objects in the frame.

Any idea how can I manually find out the html code of this frame?

Following is the page source...

```
<span class="iamenuitem" href="javascript:openInIFrame('iamain', 'lister.phtml%3f.op%3d1750%26.sess%3djj7hc78-y3XBKbsRijNPAj_RdcA.%26.ifmod%3dcm%26.done%3diaflash.phtml%253F.id%253D3%2526.mod%253Dcm%2526.sess%253Djj7hc78-y3XBKbsRijNPAj_RdcA.%2526.ifmod%253Dcm%2526.mod%253Dcm&.menuItemRefNo=137')" menuitemrefno="137" islist="true">Bank Interest and Charges</span></td>
```

Comment: That's not the page source; that's just a link (sort-of).  Right-click in the frame and there'll be a set of options for viewing just the frame source.

Comment: this is the link to the iframe that a javascript function is calling. hence in selenium, i am not able to capture the objects of this frame.

when i write a code like this..
try{
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
 System.out.println("I am in Frame 0");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='_obj__startdate']")).sendKeys("Krishan");
 }catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }

it says that the frame exists but there is no such element in the iframe. hence i am not able to perform any function on the object which is in the frame.